# Given a matrix $A$ such that $||A||<1$, prove that $I-A$ is invertible

Tags: calculus, normed-spaces

Note: This is a question seen in class while discussing metric spaces and norms, so my recollection might not be 100% accurate.

I saw a proof in class, but I wanted to know if there was a different way.

Let's assume that $I-A$ is singular. Then the equation $(I-A)v=0$ has more than just the trivial solution, therefore there exists a vector $v\ne0$ s.t. $Av = Iv$, contradicting the fact that $||A||<1$.

Does the norm have to be an operational norm for this to be correct?

Would this proof work?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yep, that's a perfectly fine proof. If $Av = v \neq 0$ then $\frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|} = 1 \leq \sup_u \frac{\|Au\|}{\|u\|} =: \|A\|$, if you want to add more details.

Comment: You argument works for finite dimensional matrix; the one given by nayrb works for infinite matrix(operator) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that
$$B = I + A + A^2 + A^3 + \cdots$$
is well defined for $||A||<1$ then compute $(I-A)B$ and $B(I-A)$.

Comment: That's the proof shown in class, I thought I had an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

You proof is correct but yes, it works only for operator norms.

Note that the proof mentioned in nayrb's answer requires sub-multiplicativity ($\|AB\|\leq\|A\|\,\|B\|$), which does not hold for all norms. It does however hold for the operator norms.